# Neovim deletes itself after some time

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

I'm new to Vim/Neovim and I'm taking the firsts steps on the editor, but for some unknown reason the nvim.exe binary just deleted itself from the folder three times.

The first time I installed via

```
choco install neovim
```

and it was working fine, but suddenly the app closed (was using via Windows Terminal, and the tab just closed) and I couldn't start it again, getting

```
The term 'nvim' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Then I downloaded this repository's last build, but when I tried to unpack the `.zip` file in the same folder, I got

```
 Access to the path 'C:\tools\Neovim\bin\nvim.exe' is denied.
```

So I tried unpacking it in a different folder, and I worked fine for a while, but when installing the nvim perl plugin via `cpan`, it happened again, the exact same thing.

Again, a unpacked the files on a different folder and tried using it again, this time avoiding the perl plugin, but when editing a file on another directory, it happened a third time, so I decided to post this issue.

Did anyone have the same problem or have a clue of what might be happening?

I'm using Neovim on Windows 11 via Windows Terminal

### Update

Tried using a GUI (Neovide) to see if the problem was the Windows Terminal, but after a few days with no problem, the executable becomes once again inaccessible.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is certainly an odd one… you might want to also asked the neovim maintainers/community via their GitHub or similar

Comment: I tried to report that as a bug on their GitHub page, but got my question closed, because, as they said, it was unreproducible.

Comment: Check your antivirus or similar software

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Don't know I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maxim Kim solved it, the problem was BitDefender detecting nvim as a malware.